# Parsing JSON file with angular.js

Tags: json, angularjs, http

I want to parse the bitcoin price from a json file with angular.js.

The json source is [this blockchain api.](https://blockchain.info/de/ticker)

The code I use for angular.js:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in price">
      {{ x.15m + ', ' + x.last }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("https://blockchain.info/de/ticker")
         .success(function (response) {$scope.price = response.USD;});
  });
</script>
```

The result should be the 15m price and then comma separated the latest price.

My guess would be that I messed something up near the response.USD, but after 1 hour, I still didn't find how to do it properly.

Please help!

Comment: It must be due to cross domain request. Do you see error in console, network tab of chrome or fiddler?

Comment: **@ShankarSangoli The chrome console throws out the following:**                                                 Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$parse/syntax?p0=.15&p1=is%20an%20unexpe…5m%20%2B%20'%2C%20'%20%2B%20x.last&p4=.15m%20%2B%20'%2C%20'%20%2B%20x.last
    at Error (native)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:6:417
    at ib.throwError (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:190:165)
    at ib.parse (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:188:499)  ....

Comment: Change `{{ x.15m + ', ' + x.last }}` to `{{ x["15m"] + ', ' + x.last }} to get rid of this error. But after you pass through this error you will still have cross domain request problem.

Comment: The "cross domain request problem" is not terrible to fix though. You can initiate a server-side request for the data. Store it in a local file and when that request comes back (in your call-back function) you can send another request to your own server at the location of the file.

Comment: Also... if that helps will you please accept my answer?

Comment: If you accept an answer it gives you some Rep. Btw... did it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are actually getting an error from the blockchain site. They have a single-origin policy set up on their server which protects them from click-jacking attacks. Here is the error you are getting:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://blockchain.info/de/ticker. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '<your domain>' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Your options are to contact the site and ask them to add your server as an exception, or to use some sort of curl request from your server then have your GET request hit your local copy.

create a file called results.php, put in the following code:

```
<?php

try {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://blockchain.info/de/ticker'
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    echo $result;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 500 Unable to pull ticker results");
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Now in your script just change it to:

```
<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("results.php")
         .success(function (response) {$scope.price = response.USD;});
  });
</script>
```

Also, one last thing. Your ng-repeat is going to repeat the same thing over and over (if you can get it to work that way) because you are writing the same thing for each value in 'x'. Maybe consider changing it to:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <p>{{price['15m']}}, {{price['last']}}</p>
</div>
```